# How can I overwrite the localization strings in a library

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor-server-side

I use a 3rd party library which has 4 localized strings I need to overwrite. It's not my library so I have no access to the source code. I do know the reference keys for the 4 strings.

Is there a way, on startup in my code, to overwrite those localized string values?

Comment: I don't think so. How are the two apps related? Which process is ultimately displaying the strings, and why would one of them attempt to rewrite what the other is doing? Say you could do this, then the strings are overwritten only in your app, or in the 3rd party as well? I don't understand why an app would need resources from another app, or why an app would need to inject itself into another process to fiddle with memory contents..